# Typescript error after update of react and react-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have upgraded react and react-dom (and also @type/react and @types/react-dom) to the latest version to use react hooks. But now I am getting this type error:

> Argument of type typeof is not assignable to parameter of type
>   'ComponentType< Props & RouteComponentProps<{}, StaticContext, any>>

```
interface LoginProps {}

class Login extends React.PureComponent<LoginProps & RouteComponentProps, {}> {

}

export default withRouter(Login);
```

I suspect the type definitions to be the issue, but I cannot find out what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with the way you have tried to extend your interface.

In typescript interfaces can be extended using the `extends` keyword (ie `interfaceA extends interfaceB`) while types can be extended using the method you have used (ie `typeA & typeB`).

And since your LoginProps is an interface, your code is breaking.

try rewriting your code as

```
interface LoginProps extends RouteComponentProps {}

class Login extends React.PureComponent<LoginProps, {}> {

}
```